# Advice regarding integrating C# code with django backend

Tags: python, c#, .net, django

I use C# to convert documents (pdf, docx etc) to other formats (docx, xls, ppt etc) and my backend is written with Python (django)

I successfully wrote and loaded a c# dll which let me call it's functions and convert the documents directly from python, using pythonnet clr.

Issue is, it's slow, like marginally slower (I'd say 20 times slower) than using the same code as if I compiled and ran it as an executable  instead of loading it as a dll to python.

So I need an advice, should I just make the c# code into an executable and then call it via a subprocess with a file path argument (which will force me to write the file into the disk, call the subprocess, which will on turn read the file, and write again, and then  the python will read the output file and delete it) or is there alternative?

With the dll solution I just pass the file bytes to the dll and don't need to write a file to disk, which would be (for me) a preferable solution, but not at the cost of that big of speed difference.

I'm assuming passing the entire file's contents (bytes) as an argument to a subprocess is a bad idea memory wise and for other reasons.

Any suggestion will be very much welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the executable is faster, that sounds like a good idea.

You could modify your C# executable to [read input from the standard input stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=net-8.0), and write onto it from Python:

```
import shutil
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["my-software"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
with open("my_document.pdf", "rb") as pdf:
    shutil.copyfileobj(pdf, proc.stdin, length=131072)
proc.stdin.close()
# read the output
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```